# Conjugate variables in gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, hamiltonian-formalism, adm-formalism, canonical-conjugation

We know that in the traditional quantum mechanics the conjugate variables are position and momentum, but what is known about the elusive quantum gravity?

It came to my mind that if there is something fundamental in "action", then it might be our window into quantum gravity. That is, we may assume that the other variable must be mass $m$ that is distributed in some volume of space, and by dimensional analysis of $[h] = [m]\cdot [X]$, we can infer that $[X]=l^2/t = [area]/[second]$. This suggests that the uncertainty in mass density is inversely proportional to the "surface speed" of the volume that confines the mass. If the mass density is low, then the surface speed is well-defined; if the mass density is high, then the surface speed becomes more indefinite and perhaps this fluctuation prevents the formation of spacetime singularities.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have no idea about ADM formalism, but is it assumed that the mass distribution volume is moving and that gives rise to the conjugate momenta? In any case, I don't have technical understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

In the canonical quantum gravity, the ''coordinate variable'' in gravity is the induced metric on a Cauchy slice $h_{ij}$. The conjugate variable to this is (roughly) the extrinsic curvature $K_{ij}$.

Note that while canonical quantum gravity tells us much about quantum gravity (e.g. existence of graviton), it is widely understood that this is certainly not the entire story.